# File SDDL not equal although it should be

Tags: powershell, permissions, file-permissions, acl, ntfs

We're trying to compare NTFS permissions for files or folders using the `SDDL` attribute. The only thing we're interested in is if the ACL is equal or not, by using the SDDL and not other methods like `AccessToString` or just comparing two plain ACL objects. This is because we had issues in the past with the standard way of doing this.

So, we now run against an issue where `File1` and `File2` have exactly the same permissions when checking the `Advanced Permissions` tab in Windows. However, the SDDL says it's not equal, although we take away the `Owner O:` part from the SDDL string as indicated [here](https://jorgequestforknowledge.wordpress.com/2008/03/26/parsing-sddl-strings/), as the owner doesn't interest us.

**The code:**

```
Function Test-ACLequal {
    Param (
        $Source,
        $Target
    )

    $CompParams = @{
        ReferenceObject  = Get-Acl -LiteralPath $Source
        PassThru         = $True
    }

    $CompParams.DifferenceObject = Get-Acl -LiteralPath $Target

    $AccessParams = @{
        ReferenceObject  = ($CompParams.ReferenceObject.sddl -split 'G:', 2 | Select -Last 1)
        DifferenceObject = ($CompParams.DifferenceObject.sddl -split 'G:', 2 | Select -Last 1)
        PassThru         = $True
    }

    if (Compare-Object @AccessParams) {
        Write-Verbose 'Test-ACLequalHC: Not equal'
        $false
    }
    else {
        Write-Verbose 'Test-ACLequalHC: Equal'
        $True
    }
}

Test-ACLequal -Source $File1-Target $File2
```

You can clearly see there is a difference between both files:

```
$AccessParams.ReferenceObject
DUD:(A;ID;FA;;;BA)(A;ID;0x1200a9;;;S-1-5-21-1078081533-261478967-839522115-243052)(A;ID;0x1301ff;;;S-1
-5-21-1078081533-261478967-839522115-280880)(A;ID;0x1301ff;;;S-1-5-21-1078081533-261478967-839522115-6
96733)(A;ID;0x1301ff;;;S-1-5-21-1078081533-261478967-839522115-696745)

$AccessParams.DifferenceObject
DUD:AI(A;ID;FA;;;BA)(A;ID;0x1200a9;;;S-1-5-21-1078081533-261478967-839522115-243052)(A;ID;0x1301ff;;;S
-1-5-21-1078081533-261478967-839522115-280880)(A;ID;0x1301ff;;;S-1-5-21-1078081533-261478967-839522115
-696733)(A;ID;0x1301ff;;;S-1-5-21-1078081533-261478967-839522115-696745)
```

Is there a way to compare files by using the SDDL without running into this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Does using `.Equals` work for you here?

```
$sourceAcl = Get-Acl $source
$targetAcl = Get-Acl $target

if ($sourceAcl.sddl.Equals($targetAcl.sddl)) {
  # Do something
  ....
}
```

This includes the owner however. In your example where you're removing it, you're also converting the object to a string, so using `Compare-Object` isn't really necessary. I'm also not sure how safe the split you're using is. You could also do:

```
$sourceAcl = Get-Acl $source
$targetAcl = Get-Acl $target
$s = $sourceAcl.sddl -replace "^O:[^:]+:",""
$t = $targetAcl.sddl -replace "^O:[^:]+:",""

if ($s -eq $t) {
  # Do something
  ....
}
```

Comment: I was considering to use this `$CompParams.ReferenceObject.sddl -split '\(', 2 | Select -Last 1`

Comment: Actually using a split isn't the right thing to do at all, you need to strip that bit of the string altogether. I've updated the answer

Comment: Modifying the sddl before checking it in general doesn't look like a sensible thing to do, it doesn't look like it's meant to be analysed with string processing. It would be a lot safer to leave the object intact and compare with the `.Equals()` method

Comment: Then we compare the owner also, which we don't want. Tried your updated `replace` but it still reports a difference as the `DUD:AI` part is still there.

Comment: How have you determined that's not correct? Personally I would trust the response coming from the object over what is displayed in the GUI